# When and why do/does "staff" as a collective noun get plural/singular pronoun/verb?

Tags: grammaticality, plural-forms, collective-nouns

I know that collective nouns such as *staff*, *team*, *crew*, and *family* can get both singular and plural pronouns/verbs in different situations and contexts, but my question is only about staff when used to mean "a group of people who are personnel or employees of a same company."

When and why does *staff* get plural or singular pronoun/verb?

Comment: An [answer to a slightly different question](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/3502/748) is possibly relevant, though I'm not sure it's an exact duplicate.

Comment: It is not even a doubtful duplicate of that one and is not answering my question. Not question nor answer are about something else.

Comment: No, you're right, I wasn't attempting to suggest that it *was* a duplicate, merely to have plausible deniability. ;)

Comment: Please read my comment again. I said it is not answering my question. :)

Answer (score 1):

*Staff* is not different from other collective nouns: It takes a singular verb when it refers to the collection as whole, and a plural verb when it refers to the members of the collection taken individually.
That is for American English; in British English, collective nouns are generally regarded as plural.

See [Collective nouns with singular verbs and plural pronouns](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/001874.html).