# Plural or Singular verb for a noun without "s"

Tags: grammaticality, subject-verb-agreement

> The audience of Justin Bieber concert is/are very high!
>       The staff of Company A has/have low morale right now.

Should I use is/are or has/have in above case?

Comment: What do you mean by "high"? Do you mean the audience is high on weed or something? Or do you mean it's a large crowd?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When and why do/does "staff" as a collective noun get plural/singular pronoun/verb?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/5922/when-and-why-do-does-staff-as-a-collective-noun-get-plural-singular-pronoun-ve)

Answer (score 1):

This can vary depending on if you speak British or American English, but to be correct I have written the British version. I have added a link in the bottom that can help you understand the difference.

"Staff" and "audience" are both collective nouns, nouns that represents many people (in theory) but is considered grammatically singular.

Therefore,

> The audience of Justin Bieber concert **is** very high!
>
> The staff of Company A **has** low morale right now.

is correct.

For more information, see this EL&U post [Does “staff” take a plural verb?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3288/does-staff-take-a-plural-verb)
.

Comment: The problem with this answer is that you *didn't* give the British version. What you gave was the American version. UK English (typically) treats collective nouns as plural, not singular. That's even what's said in the question that you linked to. So, your answer is actually the opposite of what you indicate it is.